Pulumi and Docker - Can't find the image when I'm passing the path relative to the context
I'm currently using Pulumi (Go) to handle the infrastructure. I'm trying to deploy to Google Cloud's Artifact Registry with a pre-built Docker image, but I'm having issues with Docker finding the Dockerfile's path.
I get:

ERROR: resolve : lstat apps: no such file or directory

And in some other cases:
    error: an unhandled error occurred: program failed:
    waiting for RPCs: docker build -f apps/remix-app-vite/Dockerfile --target production --platform=linux/amd64 /Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/alertdown -t remix-app-dev failed with error: exit status 1

  docker:image:Image (temporal-worker-dev):
    error: ERROR: resolve : lstat apps: no such file or directory

  docker:image:Image (remix-app-dev):
    error: ERROR: resolve : lstat apps: no such file or directory

Folder Structure
I have an nx monorepo (TypeScript) with Pulumi written in go in an infrastructure:


** Golang Code that's building the image **:
type buildAndPushToArtifactRegistryInput struct {
    ctx                  *pulumi.Context
    artifactRegistryRepo *artifactregistry.Repository
    dockerImageName      string
    dockerImagePath      string
    dockerfileName       string
    provider             *gcp.Provider
}

func buildAndPushToArtifactRegistry(input *buildAndPushToArtifactRegistryInput) (*docker.Image, error) {

    if input.artifactRegistryRepo == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("artifactRegistryRepo cannot be nil")
    }

    dependingSources := []pulumi.Resource{
        input.artifactRegistryRepo,
    }

    // Get the current working directory
    workingDir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Go up to the project root (from /libs/infrastructure/src/pulumi)
    projectRoot := filepath.Join(workingDir, "../../../../")
    projectRoot = filepath.Clean(projectRoot)

    // Debug information
    fmt.Printf("Working Directory: %s\n", workingDir)
    fmt.Printf("Project Root: %s\n", projectRoot)
    fmt.Printf("Dockerfile Path: %s\n", filepath.Join("apps", input.dockerImagePath, "Dockerfile"))

    // Create Docker build args
    buildArgs := &docker.DockerBuildArgs{
        Context:    pulumi.String(projectRoot),
        Dockerfile: pulumi.String(filepath.Join("apps", input.dockerImagePath, "Dockerfile")),
        ExtraOptions: pulumi.StringArray{
            pulumi.String("--platform=linux/amd64"),
        },
        Target: pulumi.String("production"),
    }

    image, err := docker.NewImage(input.ctx, input.dockerImageName, &docker.ImageArgs{
        Build:     buildArgs,
        ImageName: pulumi.String(input.dockerImageName),
    }, pulumi.DependsOn(dependingSources), pulumi.Provider(input.provider))

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return image, nil
}

And this is how I'm calling it:
    remixDockerImage, remixDockerImageErr := buildAndPushToArtifactRegistry(&buildAndPushToArtifactRegistryInput{
        ctx:                  input.Ctx,
        artifactRegistryRepo: remixRepository,
        dockerImageName:      input.Constants.RemixAppDockerImageName,
        dockerImagePath:      input.Constants.RemixAppDockerImagePath,
        dockerfileName:       input.Constants.RemixAppDockerfileName,
        provider:             input.Provider,
    })

    if remixDockerImageErr != nil {
        return BuildAndPushDockerImagesOutput{}, remixDockerImageErr
    }

    temporalDockerImage_, temporalWorkerDockerImageErr := buildAndPushToArtifactRegistry(&buildAndPushToArtifactRegistryInput{
        ctx:                  input.Ctx,
        artifactRegistryRepo: temporalWorkerRepository,
        dockerImageName:      input.Constants.TemporalDockerImageName,
        dockerImagePath:      input.Constants.TemporalDockerImagePath,
        dockerfileName:       input.Constants.TemporalDockerfileName,
        provider:             input.Provider,
    })

In which
var remixDockerfileLocation = "apps/remix-app-vite"
var temporalDockerfileLocation = "apps/temporal-worker"
func GetConstants(pulumiContext *pulumi.Context) *Constants {
    stackName := pulumiContext.Stack()
    
    return &Constants{
        // Others omitted 
        RemixAppDockerImageName:    fmt.Sprintf("remix-app-%s", stackName),
        RemixAppDockerImagePath:    "remix-app-vite",
        RemixAppDockerfileName:     "Dockerfile",
        RemixAppDockerfileLocation: remixDockerfileLocation,
        TemporalDockerImageName:    fmt.Sprintf("temporal-worker-%s", stackName),
        TemporalDockerImagePath:    "temporal-worker",
        TemporalDockerfileName:     "Dockerfile",
    
    }
}

When I run Pulumi, I change directory to its folder:
<root>/libs/infrastructure/src/pulumi
Here are some debugging paths:
// For First app
    Working Directory: /Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/alertdown/libs/infrastructure/src/pulumi
    Project Root: /Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/alertdown
    Dockerfile Path: apps/remix-app-vite/Dockerfile

    Working Directory: /Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/alertdown/libs/infrastructure/src/pulumi
    Project Root: /Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/alertdown
    Dockerfile Path: apps/temporal-worker/Dockerfile

What I've tried:

Renaming the Dockerfile to Dockerfile.remix and Dockerfile.temporal, and passing their values respectively.
Passing the full path as the context, and no Dockerfile eg: /apps/remix-app-vite/

buildArgs := &docker.DockerBuildArgs{
        Context:    pulumi.String(projectRootToApp),
        ExtraOptions: pulumi.StringArray{
            pulumi.String("--platform=linux/amd64"),
        },
        Target: pulumi.String("production"),
    }

This one DOES detect it, but since I need the entire monorepo context, the image will fail.
I've been going back and forth with LLMs and haven't found a solution yet. Any ideas?

I found the solution!
Docker around 2 years ago introduced the ability to support multiple build contexts as shown here.
You do so by specifying a special flag called: --build-context
This is what I did:

I set the Context to the full path of the Docker image.

E.g:
(Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/myproject/apps/remix-app-vite)

I then passed the root directory as a build context flag: --build-context root=<the-project-absolute-path-to-root>

E.g:
--build-context root=Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/myproject
I added this in the ExtraOptions of the DockerBuild command
This is how it looks in Pulumi go code:
    // Go up to the project root (from /libs/infrastructure/src/pulumi)
    projectRoot := filepath.Join(workingDir, "../../../../")
    projectRoot, err = filepath.Abs(projectRoot)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get absolute path: %w", err)
    }

    // Construct the absolute path to the Dockerfile
    dockerfilePath := filepath.Join(projectRoot, "apps", input.dockerImagePath)

    // Verify the Dockerfile exists
    if _, err := os.Stat(dockerfilePath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("dockerfile not found at path: %s", dockerfilePath)
    }

    // Debug information
    // fmt.Printf("Working Directory: %s\n", workingDir)
    // fmt.Printf("Project Root: %s\n", projectRoot)
    // fmt.Printf("Dockerfile Path: %s\n", dockerfilePath)

    // Create Docker build args using absolute paths
    buildArgs := &docker.DockerBuildArgs{
        Context: pulumi.String(dockerfilePath),
        ExtraOptions: pulumi.StringArray{
            pulumi.String("--platform=linux/amd64"),
            pulumi.String("--build-context"),
            pulumi.String(fmt.Sprintf("root=%v", projectRoot)),
        },
        Target: pulumi.String("production"),
    }

And this is an excerpt of the Dockerfile:
# Copy workspace files
COPY --from=root package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
COPY --from=root patches/ ./patches/
COPY --from=root nx.json tsconfig.base.json ./

# Copy the built files from NX
COPY --from=root apps/remix-app-vite/build ./build

